# How to detect objects with with touching each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to be able to detect if 2 separate object are touching each other. I have no idea if there is a specific piece of code to do this.

so i made some code that detects if the object the code is attached to is touching something but i don't know how to make it detect if 2 objects with different tags are touching

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Rocket")
        {
            istouchingrocket = true;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground3")
        {
            Isend = true;   //Ground three is the ending platform. This piece of code is attached to oil which is not touching this. I need to detect if the player is touching "Ground3".
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Rocket")
        {
            istouchingrocket = false;
        }
    }
```

So the code is attached to the oil and when the player touches "ground3" they gain the ability to destroy the oil. The code needs to detect remotely if 2 separate objects are touching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better for the player script to have a field that keeps track of if it has gained the ability to destroy oil:

```
public bool canDestroyOil;
```

Be sure to set it to `false` in `Start()`:

```
canDestroyOil=false;
```

Then when player detects if it touches "ground3" then set it to `true`:

```
canDestroyOil = true;
```

And then in the oil script, when it touches player it destroys itself if the player can destroy oil:

```
if (player.canDestroyOil) {
    gameObject.Destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IsTouching()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html) function.

It does exactly what you're asking.